# Ruby syntax for while block in one line

Tags: ruby

Could you please tell, what is the Ruby syntax for `while` block in one line?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For example

```
puts a[i+=1] while i < 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
while 1 do puts "hello" end
```